# Solving an ode of first order

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve this first order ode:

$$ x'(1+t^2) \sin(x)-2t \cos(x)=0 $$
$x(1)= \frac{ \pi}{3} $

I want to use the separation method, so  :

$ x' (1+t^2) \sin(x)= 2t \cos(x) $

$\leftrightarrow x'= \frac{2t \cos (x)}{(1+t^2) \sin(x)  }$

$ \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{2t \cos (x)}{(1+t^2) \sin(x)  } $
$\leftrightarrow \frac{ \sin(x) }{ \cos(x) } dx= 2t \frac{1}{1+t^2} dt $

so i have to solve:

$ \int \frac{ \sin(x) }{ \cos(x) } dx= \int 2t \frac{1}{1+t^2} dt $

$\leftrightarrow- \log( |cos(x)|) + c_1 = \log(t^2+1)+ c_2 $

from here I am not sure: If I use the exponential functin on both sides, I get:
$ - \cos(x) = t^2+1 $
then what? Can I take $ \arccos $ ? but what is then $ \arccos(cos(x)) $?

appreciate any help solving this ode :-)

Comment: You dont need two constants one is enough and you should have  $\frac 1 {\cos x}=c(t^2+1)$

Answer (score 1):

From your last line you get $$\log\left(|\cos x |\cdot(t^2+1)\right)= \log c \hspace{1 cm} \text{(for some c)} \\ \implies \cos x\cdot(t^2+1)= \pm c =C \\ \implies \cos x = \frac{C}{t^2+1}$$

Using $x(1)=\frac{\pi}{3}$, $$\cos x =\frac{1}{t^2+1} \\ x= \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{t^2+1} \right) + 2n\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake in this step here:
$$\leftrightarrow- \log( |\cos(x)|) + c_1 = \log(t^2+1)+ c_2$$
Taking $\exp$ of both sides,
$$e^{- \log( |\cos(x)|) + c_1}=e^{\log(t^2+1)+ c_2}$$
$$K_1(\cos(x))^{-1}=K_2(t^2+1)$$
$$\cos(x)=\frac{K_1}{K_2(t^2+1)}$$
Now take $\arccos$ of both sides and you're done.